# how to fetch a single field in controller from the data fetched from the model

Tags: php, arrays, controller

this is my controller code please tell me how to fetch the single value from the data.

```
 public function biasses_view()
{
    $biaso_id=base64_decode($_GET['view']);
    $this->load->model('biaso_model');
    $data['result']=$this->biaso_model->select_single_biaso1($biaso_id);
    $anchor=$result[0]->anchor_name;
    echo $anchor;
    exit;
    $data['resultshow']=$this->biaso_model->select_single_biaso($biaso_id);
    $this->load->view('admin/biasses_view',$data);
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any error over here? Post your model code? And a quick fix is `$anchor=$result[0]->anchor_name;` should be `$anchor=$data['result'][0]->anchor_name;` here I've changed `$result` into `$data['result']`

Comment: What is the output of: print_r($result); ?

Comment: data is coming from the model ..... i m trying to take a particular field in a variable which is $anchor .....

Comment: the output of: print_r($data); is Array ( [result] => CI_DB_mysql_result Object ( [conn_id] => Resource id #31 [result_id] => Resource id #36 [result_array] => Array ( ) [result_object] => Array ( ) [custom_result_object] => Array ( ) [current_row] => 0 [num_rows] => 1 [row_data] => ) )

Comment: the output of: print_r($result); is an error

Comment: anybody there ??? plz telll me how to do that

Comment: Post your model code

Comment: public function select_single_biaso($biaso_id)
{
     
     $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('TN_biaso');
        $this->db->where('biaso_id', $biaso_id);
        $query = $this->db->get();
    
     return $query->result();
}